# Can't boot into Debian 9 from Windows boot manager

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I used EasyBCD to make dual boot between windows 7 and debian 8 and it work fine
but when i installed new debian version i can't boot to debian 9 i get grub4dos ... error msg
i use the same steps of debian 8 to install debian 9 but doesn't work
+ when i create new partition and i installed debian 8 and, debian 9 is installed in other partition, i can boot normal in debian 8 and 9 with the grub menu

Answer (score 0):

From my experience do not use EasyBCD. Why because the system will not boot at all. I would use Linux boot manager and pick Windows 7.
Edit: 
EasyBCD will crash your System. I would try using Virtualbox first.

Comment: Yes if i installed grub in mbr all work fine
but me i want to use Windows boot manager not Linux